# Jquery body replacement when flash is messing around

Tags: jquery, flash, replace, comments

Hello stackoverflow friends,

I'm trying to replace some contents in a website by using the following code:

```
var newbody = $('body').html().replace(oldvalue, newvalue);
$('body').html(newbody);
```

The problem is that I have some flash embedded on the DOM and whenever I try to do the replacement the browser crashes.
Somebody should thing that a prepend or append in the right place should be a better method
to achieve this, but the elements I'm trying to locate and replace are html comments and the append prepend methods do not seem to work with this kind of nodes so they have to be treated as literal strings.

Any light on this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Another solution that should suit for my problem is to find a way to get the parent of an html comment, like this one:
<div id="container"><!--Here comes a comment--></div>
Parent = container

Answer (score 0):

You are using replace on the body. You may be accidentally destroying some of your document elements or element attributes.
For example:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var newbody = jQuery("body").html().replace("div", "input");
    jQuery("body").html(newbody);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>div is some content</div>
</body>
</html>
```

A much better approach would be to add a class to the text with wish to change and use jQuery to change the text in all elements with that class.

As for you comment traversal, you will need to use DOM types like so:

```
    $(function() {
        $("body").contents().filter(function(){
            return this.nodeType == 8;
        }).each(function(i, e){
            alert(e.nodeValue);
        });
    });
```